# How to implement a user level security and restriction to access jsp pages in java?

Tags: java, security, servlets, restriction

i want to know what tool, java api or libraries that can help me to implement security and restriction to my jsp pages. I'm using MVC model 2 approach in my application.

Case Scenario:

1. User that is not allowed to enter to certain page must not enter to the page.
2. User that is not allowed to insert or update records must be restricted.
3. Accessing resources and files must be an admin.

I've search a lot to the internet about my concern but i can't seem to find one. Please help, Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on my recent investigation, most common options to implement security in Java are:

- JAAS
- Spring Security
- Apache Shiro

Since you seems to be looking for rather basic mechanisms for permision checks, Apache Shiro may be best option to start with - it is simplier than others, integrates with Spring Framework and also has built-in JSP integration (some tag library to add permission checks right to your JSP page).